# Regular Expression to get the SRC of images in C#

Tags: c#, regex, image, src

I'm looking for a regular expression to isolate the src value of an img. 
(I know that this is not the best way to do this but this is what I have to do in this case)

I have a string which contains simple html code, some text and an image. I need to get the value of the src attribute from that string. I have managed only to isolate the whole  tag till now.

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(original_text, @"(<img([^>]+)>)").Value;
```

Comment: Run a second regex on the img tag to get the src attribute

Comment: Obligatory link to [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(original_text, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This Regex will only work if Src is the first attribute of the Image, If Src comes after ID or some other attributes, then it'll not work

Comment: @ShreekumarS why? There is a `.+?` between img and src, so there can be all kinds of characters ...

Comment: This one is Fine

`Regex.Match(original_text, "<img.*?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;`

Comment: I would make it a little more greedier, <img.*src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*>

.* instead of .+?, certainly for the last one, otherwise you always require 1 minimum character. It might not be there if they just close the img tag right after the src attribute.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make this greedy, what if there are more than one img-elements? Your expression might capture all these elements as one match. But you are right about the end of my expression, I changed it to .*? to allow the element to end after the src attribute. The first .+? is still right, there has to be at least one character between img and src: the space ...

Answer (score 15):

I know you say you have to use regex, but if possible i would really give this open source project a chance:
[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

It is really easy to use, I just discovered it and it helped me out a lot, since I was doing some heavier html parsing. It basically lets you use XPATHS to get your elements.

Their example page is a little outdated, but the API is really easy to understand, and if you are a little bit familiar with xpaths you will get head around it in now time

The code for your query would look something like this: (uncompiled code)

```
 List<string> imgScrs = new List<string>();
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(htmlText);//or doc.Load(htmlFileStream)
 var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//img[@src]"); s
 foreach (var img in nodes)
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = img["src"];
    imgScrs.Add(att.Value)
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it looks like the HtmlAgilityPack's api has changed. I have posted an alternative solution to this question

Answer (score 7):

I tried what Francisco Noriega suggested, but it looks that the api to the HtmlAgilityPack has been altered. Here is how I solved it:

```
        List<string> images = new List<string>();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string site = "http://www.mysite.com";
        var htmlText = client.DownloadString(site);

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument()
                    {
                        OptionFixNestedTags = true,
                        OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true
                    };

        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);

        foreach (HtmlNode img in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute att = img.Attributes["src"];
            images.Add(att.Value);
        }
```

Comment: You should really put //img[@src] in the `SelectNodes` call (or check for its existence before getting the `att.Value`.. And either check the result for null or tack `?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null);` to the call of `SelctNodes`. You'll get `NullReferenceException` otherwise.

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer, you could also edit the original answer to remove the errors contained in there.

Answer (score 3):

This should capture all img tags and just the src part no matter where its located (before or after class etc) and supports html/xhtml :D

```
<img.+?src="(.+?)".+?/?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex you want should be along the lines of:

```
(<img.*?src="([^"])".*?>)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a look behind to do it without needing to pull out a group

```
(?<=<img.*?src=")[^"]*
```

remember to escape the quotes if needed

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to get the  tags out of strings:

```
</? *img[^>]*>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the one I use:

```
<img.*?src\s*?=\s*?(?:(['"])(?<src>(?:(?!\1).)*)\1|(?<src>[^\s>]+))[^>]*?>
```

The good part is that it matches any of the below:

```
<img src='test.jpg'>
<img src=test.jpg>
<img src="test.jpg">
```

And it can also match some unexpected scenarios like extra attributes, e.g:

```
<img src = "test.jpg" width="300">
```