# Get img src from XML CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, regex, windows, cdata

I am new to C# and Windows Phone development so forgive me if I am missing the obvious:

I would like to display a thumbnail image from an RSS XML feed located at http://blog.dota2.com/feed/. The image is inside a CDATA tag written in HTML. Here is the XML code:

```
    <content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p>We celebrate Happy Bear Pun Week a day earlier as Lone Druid joins Dota 2&#8242;s cast of heroes.</p> <p><a href="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/LoneDruid_full.jpg "><img class="alignnone" title="The irony is that he's allergic to fur." src="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/LoneDruid_small.jpg" alt="The irony is that he's allergic to fur." width="551" height="223" /></a></p> <p>Community things:</p> <ul> <li><a href="http://www.itsgosu.com/game/dota2/articles/ig-monthly-madness-invitational-finals-mar-29_407" target="_blank">It&#8217;s Gosu&#8217;s Monthly Madness</a> tournament finals are tomorrow, March 29th. You don&#8217;t want to miss this, we hear it could be more than we can bear.</li> <li>Bear witness to <a href="http://www.team-dignitas.net/articles/blogs/DotA/1092/Dota-2-Ultimate-Guide-to-Warding/" target="_blank">Team Dignitas&#8217; Ultimate Guide to Warding</a>. This should be required teaching in clawsrooms across the globe.</li> <li>Great Explorer Nullf has <a href="http://nullf.deviantart.com/#/d4ubxiu" target="_blank">compiled the eating habits</a> of the legendary Tidehunter in one handy chart. This might give you paws before deciding to head to the beach.</li> </ul> <p>Bear in mind that there will not be an update next week as we will be hibernating during that time.</p> <p>Today&#8217;s bearlog is available <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/news/7662" target="_blank">here</a>.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p>Bear.</p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
```

I just need the 
`<img src="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/LoneDruid_small.jpg" />`
so I can use the URL to display the image in my reader app.

I have heard people saying not to use Regex as it is bad practise for parsing HTML. I am creating this as a proof of concept, and don't need to worry about this. I am looking for the quickest way to get this URL for the image, and then call this in my app.

Does anyone have any help?
Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: just parse the xml, it is so much easier!

Comment: any suggestions for the best way to do this? :)

Comment: if you insist on regex try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257359/regular-expression-to-get-the-src-of-images-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your xml looks like this (which I'm sure it doesn't), and these extensions: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:content='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'>
  <content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
<p>We celebrate ...</p> 
<p>
  <a href="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/LoneDruid_full.jpg ">
    <img class="alignnone" title="The irony is that he's allergic to fur." 
        src="http://media.steampowered.com/apps/dota2/posts/LoneDruid_small.jpg" />
  </a>
</p> 
<p>the rest removed</p> 
]]>
  </content:encoded>
</root>
```

This will get the image source from the second paragraph - hard coded and ugly, but it was all you needed you said.  You will have to give the path to the `path/to/content:encoded` for it to work, and if it is in a group (aka array) then it will be even more complicated.  From my code you can see how to separate out the arrays (see paras):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file) // or .Parse(string)
string html = root.Get("content:encoded", string.Empty).Replace("&nbsp", " ");
XElement xdata = XElement.Parse(string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", html));
XElement[] paras = xdata.GetElements("p").ToArray();
string src = paras[1].Get("a/img/src", string.Empty);
```

**PS** this works because the HTML is properly formed, if it isn't, then you'll have to use the HtmlAgilityPack as others have answered.  You can use the `html` returned from the `Get("content:emcoded" ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this when you are ready to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourstring);
var imgLinks = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("img")
    .Select(n => n.Attributes["src"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string pattern = @"<img.+?src.*?\=.*?""(<?URL>.*?)""";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(myCDataText);
var domain = match.Groups["URL"].Value;
```