# Regular expression to replace image tag src attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a `string` that contains html code of a document.

It can have `multiple image tags` inside.

What I want to do is to pass the img tag's `src` attribute value i.e. url to a C# function and replace that value with the function returns.

How can I do this?

Comment: The <center> cannot hold it is too late.

Comment: If you could post what you tried so far, it might be easier to understand.

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257359/regular-expression-to-get-the-src-of-images-in-c-sharp

Comment: `-1` this question has been asked here many many times!

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not a good for parsing HTML files.HTML is not strict nor is it regular with its format.(for example: in non strict html its **OK** to have a tag without a closing tag)

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can use `htmlagilitypack` to do it like this

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(yourStream);

foreach(var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]"))//select only those img that have a src attribute..ahh not required to do [@src] i guess
{
 item.Attributes["src"].Value=yourFunction(item.Attributes["src"].Value);
}
doc.Save("yourFile");//dont forget to save
```

Comment: I am passing HTML in string and I want to return that string with replaced values. I don't want to save it in file. How do I do it?

Comment: @DevendraGohil use `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to get the full html