# only get the src value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have in  the database a field that will always have an  tag. and also lots of text..

**For example:**

```
Hey there.. whats up?
<img src="http://cdn.theatlantic.com/static/infocus/ngpc112812/s_n01_nursingm.jpg" alt="" />
.. and this is my photo!..
```

I need to get ONLY what between the

> src

I tried :

```
public string LinkPicCorrect(string path)
{
    //string input = "[img]http://imagesource.com[/img]";
    string pattern = @"\<img>([^\]]+)\\/>";
    string result = Regex.Replace(path, pattern, m =>
    {
        var url = m.Groups[1].Value;
        // do something with url here
        // return the replace value
        return @"<img src=""" + url + @""" border=""0"" />";
    },
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    result = "<img src='" + result + "'/>";

    return result;
}
```

But I've got a parsing error :

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: parsing "\([^]]+)\/>" - Reference to undefined group name img.

dont know though if my code is the right path...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257450/2699126).

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(original_text, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: it does not work if there is no prop after src. you have to add like ált' or something after source. replace "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>" with "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+*>"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Regex pattern:-

```
string pattern= Regex.Match(path, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: @thormayer:- May I know what was wrong in my answer as it was neither upvoted nor accepted as the other answer was just a  copy paste of my answer!!!! :(

Comment: My answer is not a copy/paste of yours, but a copy of an already answered question that I quoted. Please don't rage for something like this... It's a Q/A website, not a leaderboard.