# How to get substring from html element string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I use asp.net project in server side.

I have this string: `<img src="../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg" style="width:190px">`

at some point I need to extruct src from string:

```
../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg
```

How can I get substring using c#?

Comment: may be worth checking out this if you're able to use it and this problem isn't a one time thing. Makes extracting that info easier. http://html-agility-pack.net/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c etc etc.. The real question is : **Do you need a Html parser or it's a one time job on a simple string?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [only get the src value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330460/only-get-the-src-value)

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835868/how-to-get-img-src-or-a-hrefs-using-html-agility-pack .. man to mutch good post about it. any Google 'C# get img src' will give you result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some regex to solve that...

```
var test = "<img src=\"../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg\" style=\"width:190px\">";

var pattern = @"<img src=""([^\""]*)";

var result = Regex.Match(test, pattern).Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The issue is... if you're performing that function against any html document with multiple image tags, it's not going to work, to get them all...

```
test = "<img src=\"../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg\" style=\"width:190px\"><img src=\"../../SpatialData/sometext/814.jpg\" style=\"width:190px\">";

var matches = Regex.Matches(test, pattern)
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value);

foreach (var m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

As someone has already stated, HTML agility pack is an option worth looking into, the solution I've provided above is very rigid, if the attributes on the image tag were to be reordered differently, those elements would not be included in the results

Comment: Thanks for post! But I have this string:"<img src="../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg" style="width:190px">"

whithout - "\"

Comment: its the same... ive escaped that string so that the console app can execute

Comment: Correct me if this is wrong https://dotnetfiddle.net/04pwvH 

I've deliberately escaped that string because of the quotes in the string.  

When you execute that you get that same output

Comment: So `var test = "<img src=\"../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg\" style=\"width:190px\">";` == `<img src="../../SpatialData/sometext/813.jpg" style="width:190px">`